# How can I fix a partial Homebrew installation OSX 10.9?

Tags: macos, mac, homebrew, osx-mavericks

Im new to command line stuff and I was trying to install Homebrew in order to install gstreamer on my Mac. I was following instructions and got to the point where `brew doctor` gave me a list of errors about the things in `/usr/local`. After reading that OS X doesnt use that directory I `rm -rf` the directories in local. Since then `brew doctor` returns command not found and if I try to reinstall Brew the terminal just hangs.

```
$ /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(/usr/bin/curl -fksSL http://ow.ly/aAiPj"
>
```

IS there anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a missing closing parenthesis on your command.

The command should be:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
```

Comment: Ah! Thanks, that plus cleaning out /local and now Im ready to brew. Thanks.